# Time calculation in PHP using Loop

Tags: php, mysql, time

i want to insert multiple data in database according to selected `start_time` and `end_time`. I already get the calculation for the time. But, when i run the query insert it weird on sixtieth minutes *(in bolder output)*.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
    $start_hour = "05";
    $start_min = "30";

    $end_hour = "06";
    $end_min = "05";

    $start_hour = substr($start_hour,1,1);
    $end_hour = substr($end_hour,1,1);

    $start_time = $start_hour.$start_minute;
    $end_time = $end_hour.$end_minute;

    if($start_hour < $end_hour) {
        for($i=$start_hour; $i<=$end_hour; $i++) {
            //$i = (($i < 10))? "0".$i: $i;

            if($i == $end_hour) {
                $start_min = "00";
            }

            for($j=$start_min; $j<60; $j+=5) {
                $j = (($j < 10) && ($j != 0))? "0".$j: $j;
                $time = "0".$i.$j;
                $time2 = "0".($i.$j+5);
                echo "<br/>";   

                // Lakukan insert disini
                echo "INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='$time' AND end_time='$time2'";

                if($i == $end_hour && $j == $end_min) { break; }
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

And here is the output :

> INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0530' AND end_time='0535'
>   INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0535' AND end_time='0540'
>   INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0540' AND end_time='0545'
>   INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0545' AND end_time='0550'
>   INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0550' AND end_time='0555'
>   **INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0555' AND end_time='0560'**
>   INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0600' AND end_time='0605'
>   INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='0605' AND end_time='0610'

How to make `0560` to `0600` in the output above?

Thank you.

Comment: It's because you're adding 5 when you assign `$time2`. The loop stops at 55, and 55+5 is 60.

Comment: A separate issue: `if($i == $end_hour)` should be `if($i != $start_hour)`.

Comment: If it were me, I would start with a UNIX time stamp as my time var, and manipulate that variable by adding the appropriate amount of seconds.  This seems like a strange way to handle time data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DateTime objects to achieve this:

```
$start = new DateTime("$start_hour:$start_min");
$end = new DateTime("$end_hour:$end_min");

while ($start <= $end) {
    $start_time = $start->format('H:i');
    $start->modify('+5 minute');
    $end_time = $start->format('H:i');

    echo "INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='$start_time' AND end_time='$end_time'","<br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='05:30' AND end_time='05:35'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='05:35' AND end_time='05:40'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='05:40' AND end_time='05:45'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='05:45' AND end_time='05:50'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='05:50' AND end_time='05:55'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='05:55' AND end_time='06:00'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='06:00' AND end_time='06:05'
INSERT INTO golf_list start_time='06:05' AND end_time='06:10'
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/72394)

Comment: It works for me now, but the end time is 06:05 and the loop is end with 06:10

Comment: @fanjavaid: That's what you show in the question. Do you want to stop at `6:05`? If so, simply change `while ($start <= $end) {` to `while ($start < $end) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing time management in a strange way; specifically as a series of string concatenations, but this is what you want:

```
$jPrime = ($j + 5) % 60)
$jPrime = ($jPrime < 10) ? "0".$jPrime : $jPrime;
$iPrime = $i + floor(($j + 5) / 60)

$time2 = "0".($iPrime.$jPrime);
```

Note that you're treating each 'digit' as it's own string, and expecting rollover from one digit to another. Handling numbers as strings is enormously error prone, and you may want to back out your code so you're never using `substr`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/ 60`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `DateTime`, requiring at least PHP version 5.3.0:

```
$start = new DateTime('05:30');
$end = new DateTime('06:05');

$step = DateInterval::createFromDateString('5 minutes');

for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i->add($step))
    echo $i->format('Hi'); // put your query around this
```

Comment: `DateInterval::createFromDateString` requires PHP >= 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
<?php
    $start_hour = "05";
    $start_min = "30";

    $end_hour = "06";
    $end_min = "05";

    if($start_hour < $end_hour) {
        $time = $start_time = mktime($start_hour, $start_min);
        $end_time = mktime($end_hour, $end_min);
        while ($time <= $end_time) {
            $time2 = strtotime("+5 minute", $time);
            echo "INSERT INTO `golf_list` SET `start_time` = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) . "', `end_time` = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time2) . "'";
            echo "\n";
            $time = $time2;
        }   
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
for($j=$start_min; $j<60; $j+=5) {
```

do this:

```
for($j=$start_min; $j<=60; $j+=5) {
```

Comment: This wouldn't fix the issue.